# when deleting a row (one to many relationship) i got this excetion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Entities in 'MyModelContainer.Tablette' participate in the 'FournisseurTablette' relationship. 0 related 'Fournisseur' were found. 1 'Fournisseur' is expected.

public void Destroy(Tablette product)
        {

```
        var entity = new Tablette();

        entity.IdProduit = product.IdProduit;

        db.Tablette.Attach(entity);


        if (entity != null)
        {
            db.Tablette.Remove(entity);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

a 'Fournisseur' has many 'tablette'

Comment: Please provide your code, we can't help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in the following line:

```
db.Tablette.Attach(entity);
```

Maybe you should use `db.Tablette.Add(entity);`